# Format moment to string

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, momentjs

I have a moment value passed to a function and I try to format the moment to a string in the format *YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm* (SS-ISO 8601). The date is accurately formatted but the time value is omitted.

Code:

```
timeTransformer(value: moment.Moment) {
    return value == null ? null : value.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'); //Time is 00:00 even though I can see that moment has values 15:37:19
}
```

[image: Can somebody explain this to me?]

Comment: Do not use [Internal properties](http://momentjs.com/guides/#/lib-concepts/internal-properties/) like `_i` and `_d`.

Comment: I don´t, what do you mean? I use `value.format` where `value` is the moment value. The reason _i and _d are visible is because I wanted to show that the moment has time properties set. The image is from the `Watch` window in the Chrome console.

Comment: I wanted to sugggest to do not look at the value of `_` internal properties. If you think that something is wrong with parsing and showing value of a moment object, please share relevant code. Where does `value` come from?

Comment: You can see that the moment value has time values (hours, minutes, seconds) and so my question is - Why `format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm')` doesn´t produce "2017-10-09 15:37" instead of "2017-10-09 00:00".

Comment: If you write moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm') on your console, you'll se that it actually prints the current date AND time. Try to convert your value to a Javascript date with value.toDate() and check if it contains the time information.

Comment: Again, do not look at `_i` value, but please share the code you are using to create `value` var.

Comment: @LucaDeNardi, no it does not contain the time, how is that? the internal variable obviously holds the time and it complies with the value sent from the server, so why is it lost?

@VincenzoC, Why not look at the internal variabel - the time is correct? The `value` variable is bound to a datatable and this function is called from there as a formatting function

Comment: @Marcus you should then check how that Moment object is created (for example parsing it without specifying the time), and if it is edited somehow (for example by calling value.startOf('day')).

Comment: @Marcus because momentjs [guide](http://momentjs.com/guides/#/lib-concepts/internal-properties/) suggest to do not do so: _the values of `_d` and any other properties prefixed with `_` should not be used for any purpose._. I think that the your problem is the way `value` is created.

Comment: @VincenzoC Yeah, I realize that - I am not trying to _"use them for any purpose"_ - simply stating that the moment object holds the time values I need yet fails to evaluate to correct time format. One would assume that if the time data was  lost, the object wouldn´t hold them.

Comment: @Marcus I'm totally convinced that the issue is the way you "create" moment object. James Thorpe's answer shows an example of wrong parsing that may lead to your situation. Since you stated that _The moment object is not "created" programatically, it´s just an Observable list of objects bound to a datatable_ I think that you have to edit your question (or post a new one) sharing also server side code to get further help.

Comment: @VincenzoC, yes, you are right. It´s a third-party framework - had to deepdive and edit some code in there where moment was created from parsing only the `date`. I still think it´s weird though that the moment object retains the time data even when it is explicitly told to only use `date` - really confusing imho.

Comment: @Marcus It'll be to do with when it's dealing with timezones etc - even when dealing with just the date part, it needs to know times as depending on the timezone, even the date might change.

Comment: @JamesThorpe Naturally - thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per [the documentation](http://momentjs.com/guides/#/lib-concepts/internal-properties/):

> As such, the values of `_d` and any other properties prefixed with `_` should not be used for any purpose.

Having said that, we can explain what's going on.  In your case, we can see both `_i` and `_f` are set.  `_i` would appear to be used to store the initial value you passed to moment.  `_f` looks to store the format you told moment to parse the input with.  See here:

```js
var m = moment('2017/10/04 12:34:56', 'YYYY/MM/DD');
console.log(m._i);
console.log(m._f);
console.log(m.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

The `_i` property is set in the same way, but logging `.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm')` shows the same `00:00` you see.  This is because I told moment to parse it as `YYYY/MM/DD` - you used `YYYY-MM-DD`.

To get the time working, you need to go and alter the code that is creating your moment object.

Comment: He is not using the _i and _f variables, I think he just showed them in the console to explain that the Date initially had the time in it.

Comment: @LucaDeNardi I know.  _I'm not using them either_.  I'm logging them to demonstrate what moment is doing internally and that his issue lies where the moment object is created.  I even prefaced my answer with the documented warning not to use them, but the values that are in them can still be used to point out what's happening.

Comment: Look, the time in internal variable `_i` which I am NOT USING in any way holds the correct time set on the server side where the DateTime variable (.NET) is originally created and that is the purpose I showed it and is telling me that the value was accurately set. The moment object is not "created" programatically, it´s just an Observable list of objects bound to a datatable.

Comment: @JamesThorpe ok, I think you got the point (that I was missing), but I think your answer is incomplete, I would have shown the way to parse the input correctly. (Even if we are not sure that the OP is trying to parse the `"2017/10/04 12:34:56"` string)

Comment: @Marcus Your underlying issue would then appear to be in the datatable binding code - something somewhere is constructing the moment object, and it's doing it with only the date format specifier.  Either way, you've not included it in your question, so there's not a lot that can be said about it.